# how to reduce the size of png image in pdf (compress png in pdf)

Tags: java, pdf, itext, png

I want to reduce the size of pdf file by replacing the high-resolution image with a lower-resolution image. To complete the issue, I have to:

1. extract the images(streams) from pdf
2. compress the images
3. replace the images(streams) in the pdf with compressed images

When I extract png images and replace them, the transparent background changes to a black background. I extract the images from the pdf to figure out the reason. There is something very strange that pdf uses to stream to save a png. So if I attempt to extract a png image from a pdf, I will get two different images: an 8-bit color image and a 24-bit color image.

```
...
1 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 1920/Height 1035/Length 24720/ColorSpace/DeviceGray/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
...
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 1920/Height 1035/SMask 1 0 R/Length 47751/ColorSpace[/CalRGB<</Gamma[2.2 2.2 2.2]/Matrix[0.41239 0.21264 0.01933 0.35758 0.71517 0.11919 0.18045 0.07218 0.9504]/WhitePoint[0.95043 1 1.09]>>]/Intent/Perceptual/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
...
endstream
...
```

Original image(32-bit color image with a transparent background):
[image: original image]

An 8-bit color image: 
[image: 8-bit color]

An 24-bit color image:
[image: 24-bit color]

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

`ImageExtractor` will help you to extract images from the Pdf file.

```java
public class ImageExtractor {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImageExtractor.class);

    public void extract(File pdf, File imageDir) throws IOException {
        if(!imageDir.exists()) {
            imageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(pdf);
        PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
        System.out.println("PDPageTree#count: " + list.getCount());
        int pageIndex = 1;
        for (PDPage page : list) {
            PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
            System.out.println(pdResources.toString());
            for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#COSName: " + c.getName());
                PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#PDXObject: " + o.toString());
                // https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/ImageExtraction.java
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    File file = new File(imageDir, pageIndex + "-" + System.nanoTime() + "." + img.getSuffix());
                    ImageIO.write(((PDImageXObject)o).getImage(), img.getSuffix(), file);
                }
            }
            pageIndex ++;
        }
        log.info("Images have been extracted successfully! Check your images folder.");
    }
}
```

`ReplaceHightResolutionImage` is the code I use to reduce the size of pdf.

```java
package io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize.itext;

import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfNumber;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfObject;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject;
import io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize.imagecompress.ImageCompressor;
import io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize.imagecompress.SimpleCompress;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReplaceHightResolutionImage {

    private ImageCompressor compressor;
    private double quality;
    private double scale;

    public ReplaceHightResolutionImage(double quality, double scale) {
        this.compressor = new SimpleCompress();
        this.quality = quality;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public ReplaceHightResolutionImage(double quality, double scale, ImageCompressor compressor) {
        this.compressor = compressor;
        this.quality = quality;
        this.scale = scale;
    }

    public void replace(File pdf, File output) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdf));
        int n = reader.getXrefSize();
        PdfObject object;
        PRStream stream;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            object = reader.getPdfObject(i);
            stream = findImageStream(object);
            if (stream == null) {
                continue;
            }
            PdfImageObject pdfImageObject = new PdfImageObject(stream);
            BufferedImage bi = pdfImageObject.getBufferedImage();
            if (bi == null) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("PdfReader#Xref: " + i + "," + pdfImageObject.getFileType());
            BufferedImage resultImage = compressor.compress(bi, pdfImageObject.getFileType(), quality, scale);
            replaceImage(stream, resultImage);
        }

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(output));
        // furtherCompress(reader, stamper);
        stamper.close();
    }

    private void furtherCompress(PdfReader reader, PdfStamper stamper) throws DocumentException {
        reader.removeFields();
        reader.removeUnusedObjects();
        stamper.setFullCompression();
        stamper.getWriter().setCompressionLevel(PdfStream.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
    }

    private PRStream findImageStream(PdfObject object) {
        PRStream stream;
        if (object == null || !object.isStream()) {
            return null;
        }
        stream = (PRStream)object;
        System.out.println(stream.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE));
        if (!PdfName.IMAGE.equals(stream.getAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {
            // not jpg or png
            return null;
        }
        PdfName pdfName = stream.getAsName(PdfName.FILTER);
        if (!PdfName.DCTDECODE.equals(pdfName) && !PdfName.FLATEDECODE.equals(pdfName)) {
            return null;
        }
        // if (PdfName.DCTDECODE.equals(filter)) {
        //     return PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.JPG.getFileExtension();
        // } else if (PdfName.JPXDECODE.equals(filter)) {
        //     return PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.JP2.getFileExtension();
        // } else if (PdfName.FLATEDECODE.equals(filter)) {
        //     return PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.PNG.getFileExtension();
        // } else if (PdfName.LZWDECODE.equals(filter)) {
        //     return PdfImageObject.ImageBytesType.CCITT.getFileExtension();
        // }
        return stream;
    }

    private void replaceImage(PRStream stream, BufferedImage resultImage) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream imgBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(resultImage, "JPG", imgBytes);

        stream.clear();
        stream.setData(imgBytes.toByteArray(), false, PRStream.NO_COMPRESSION);
        stream.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
        stream.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
        stream.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE);
        stream.put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(resultImage.getWidth()));
        stream.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(resultImage.getHeight()));
        stream.put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
        stream.put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
    }
}
```

```java
package io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize.itext;

public class ThumbnailatorCompressor implements ImageCompressor {

    @Override
    public BufferedImage compress(BufferedImage image, String imageFormat, double quality, double scale) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ThumbnailatorCompressor#type: " + image.getType());
        // int imageType = "png".equalsIgnoreCase(imageFormat)? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB: image.getType();
        BufferedImage thumbnail = Thumbnails.of(image)
            .imageType(image.getType())
            .scale(scale)
            .outputQuality(quality)
            // .outputFormat(imageFormat)
            .useOriginalFormat()
            .asBufferedImage();

        return thumbnail;
    }
}
```

- [horse.pdf](https://gitlab.com/DoneSpeak/tutorial/-/blob/master/pdf/asset/horse.pdf)
- [horse.png](https://gitlab.com/DoneSpeak/tutorial/-/blob/master/pdf/asset/images/horse.png)

```java
public class ReplaceHightResolutionImageTest {

    @Test
    public void reduceWithThumbnailatorCompressor() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        double quality = 1d;
        double scale = 0.6d;
        File pdf = new File("pdf/asset/horse.pdf");
        File output = new File("pdf/target/output", "replaced-" + quality + "-" + scale);
        ReplaceHightResolutionImage replacer = new ReplaceHightResolutionImage(quality, scale, new SimpleCompress());
        replacer.replace(pdf, output);
    }
}
```

Comment: ISO-32000-1 (aka the PDF specification) only supports two types of images - JPEG and "raw bits". So ANY source image format which is not JPEG is converted into "raw bits" - this includes BMP, TIFF, GIF, etc. PNG consists of 4 color channels: Red, Green, Blue and Alpha. RGB are essentially the same as in a Bitmap image; Alpha is the transparency layer. So what iText does to emulate PNG in a PDF, is to add not one but two images on top of one another: one image stream with the color and another image stream with the transparency mask. Those are the two images you extracted.

Comment: So calling `stream.clear()` in my `ReplaceHightResolutionImage ` will break the structure of the png stream and cause a black background. If I want to compress a png image in the pdf, what should I do?

Comment: @DoneSpeak there are not PNG images in a PDF. There's either JPEGs or raw bits. No PNGs! What you should do is compress the RGB and the Alpha (8 bit) images as two individual JPEGs and substitute them for the original, uncompressed raw bits images.

Comment: @datenwolf Thanks for your answer. As you can see in my description, I tried to compress every stream and substitute them for the original. But after that, the background of the image with a transparent background became black. It troubles me a lot.

Comment: You clear the stream dictionary, in particular the entry referencing the soft mask image. So don't remove the **SMask**. Also there may be other entries to keep, e.g. for associating the image to an optional content group. Thus, remove only what you need to remove.

Comment: @mkl I think there should be a method that can extract a whole png image and replace the whole png image instead of processing two parts of the png stream individually.

Comment: @DoneSpeak the thing is, you cannot extract a PNG image, because a PNG image does not exist in PDF. So please don't say that, please step away from that thought. That being said. You are asking for a convenience method to extract two streams and combine them into a single image of the PNG format. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: What happens if you only replace the stream with 24bits RGB raw bytes with JPEG, and don't touch the 8bits Alpha transparency mask? Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: *"I think there should be a method that can extract a whole png image and replace the whole png image instead of processing two parts of the png stream individually"* - one sometimes would wish for image extraction also adding the transparency to an extracted png if possible. But that would not help in your use case, jpeg doesn't support transparency (at least it's not supported universally), so such a *full replacement method* would also drop transparency.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse in my case, I want to reduce the width and height of the picture. So if I only process the 24bit color image, something's going to go wrong.

Comment: @DoneSpeak okay, that was information that was missing in the original question. I hope that other people who know more about PNG and Alpha transparency can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workable but not good enough answer. It compresses jpg and png very well. The only shortcoming is that if you reuse an image in many pages, it will take each image ref as an individual stream and produces a new stream to take place of the image ref which might cause a larger file size.

```
1 0 obj
<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width 1002/Height 564/Filter/DCTDecode/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 89149>>stream
...
endstream
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Length 106/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x�m�=� ��w�^@|���=� 7�/����8�6��&b0$��
��N!o��L�,?Ck'�����c�h�x0��/(5c*�Y�سEX�o�Uj3�B�ݔ"
endstream
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Resources<</XObject<</img0 1 0 R>>>>/Contents 2 0 R/Parent 3 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Length 106/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x�m�=� ��w�^@|���=�image    7�/����8�6��&b0$��
��N!o��L�,?Ck'�����c�h�x0��/(5c*�Y�سEX�o�Uj3�B�ݔ"
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]/Resources<</XObject<</img0 1 0 R>>>>/Contents 5 0 R/Parent 3 0 R>>
endobj
```

```java
package io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize;

import io.gitlab.donespeak.tutorial.pdf.reducesize.imagecompress.ThumbnailatorCompressor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.PDXObject;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.JPEGFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class RemoveAllImageFromPdf {

    public static void extractImages(File input, File imageDir) throws IOException {
        if(imageDir.exists()) {
            imageDir.delete();
        }
        imageDir.mkdirs();
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input);
        int pageIndex = 1;
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        for (PDPage page : catalog.getPages()) {
            PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
            System.out.println(pdResources.toString());
            for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#COSName: " + c.getName());
                PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#PDXObject: " + o.toString());
                // https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/ImageExtraction.java
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    System.out.println(img.getSuffix() + "-" + img.getBitsPerComponent() + "-" + img.getColorSpace());
                    File file = new File(imageDir, pageIndex + "-" + c.getName() + "-" + img.getColorSpace() + "-" + System.nanoTime() + "." + img.getSuffix());
                    ImageIO.write(((PDImageXObject)o).getImage(), img.getSuffix(), file);
                }
            }
            pageIndex ++;
        }
        // document.save(output);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param input
     * @param output
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void compress(File input, File output) throws IOException {
        if(!output.getParentFile().exists()) {
            output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        ThumbnailatorCompressor compressor = new ThumbnailatorCompressor();
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(input);
        int pageIndex = 1;
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();

        for (PDPage page : catalog.getPages()) {
            PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
            for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#COSName: " + c.getName());
                PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
                System.out.println("PDResources[" + pageIndex + "]#PDXObject: " + o.toString());
                // https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/extract/ImageExtraction.java
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                    PDImageXObject img = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    BufferedImage bufferedImage = compressor.compress(img.getImage(), img.getSuffix(), 0.8, 0.5);
                    PDImageXObject imgNew = null;
                    System.out.println("img(w, h): (" + img.getWidth() + "," + img.getHeight() + ")");
                    System.out.println("bufferedImage(w, h): (" + bufferedImage.getWidth() + "," + bufferedImage.getHeight() + ")");
                    if("png".equalsIgnoreCase(img.getSuffix())) {
                        imgNew = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);
                    } else {
                        imgNew = JPEGFactory.createFromImage(document, bufferedImage);
                    }
                    pdResources.put(c, imgNew);
                }
            }
            pageIndex ++;
        }
        if(!output.getParentFile().exists()) {
            output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        document.save(output);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

By using the following methods to process objects in the document directly, maybe we can solve the problem above. But I have no idea how to replace the stream in this way.

```java
new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdf)).getPdfObject(i);
// or
org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(pdf).getDocument().getObjects()
```